# Validate dynamically named radio buttons using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation, radio-button

I have been trawling through various examples of radio buttons validation and grasp the concept but no examples seem to fit my situation.  I have queried my database which has 4 options and for each option I have generated an associated radio button as below:

```
<?php foreach($options as $option){ ?>

<p><input type="radio" name="ID<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $option; ?>"><?php echo $option; ?></p>

<?php } ?>
```

So this basically generates 4 radio buttons per row called from the database.  This appears in the source as:

```
<form method="POST" action="Result.php">
    <p>1.  Question </p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="ID1" value="answer1">answer1</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="ID1" value="answer2">answer2</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="ID1" value="answer3">answer3</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="ID1" value="answer4">answer4</p>
    <p>2.  Question 2</p>   
        <p><input type="radio" name="ID2" value="answer1">answer1</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="ID2" value="answer2">answer2</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="ID2" value="answer3">answer3</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="ID2" value="answer4">answer4</p> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit!">          
</form>
```

etc etc.

The names of these radio buttons are partially generated by php, how can I use javascript with an associated alert to check 1 of the radio buttons from each question has been checked prior to submitting the form the questions are populated within?

Or maybe even just how can I achieve this with php ISSET?

Comment: In your `result.php`, `isset($_POST['ID1'])` will return true if one of these radio buttons from the first question was checked. Then `$_POST['ID1']` will hold the value of either answer1, answer2 and so on.

Comment: Eddi, thank you your reply, I understand this would happen within the results.php but my question was how could I verify the form within the same page prior to submitting the form on to results.php sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just JavaScript to verify whether a radio button within a radio group is checked:

```
function radiogroupSelected(name){
    var inputArr = document.getElementsByName(name);
    for(var i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++){
        if(inputArr[0].checked){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now you can call this function like `radiogroupSelected('ID1')` to determine if one of the inputs was selected.

Comment: Thank you for your help, im used this concept and expanded it for each ID. Appreciate the answer thank you!